# Mongodb won't do anything

Tags: mongodb

I'm not an expert of mongoDB and I tried to change the conf file to activate the authentication. This ultimately resulted in mongoDB completely stuck :

- My node.js apps (using mongoose) can't connect to mongo
- If I use the mongo shell and try to type basic stuff like "show dbs" I always have an answer looking like that :

> root@*:~# mongo
>
> MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3
>
> Mon Jan 21 12:46:26 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
>
> connecting to: test
>
> show dbs

```
assert failed : listDatabases failed:{
    "assertion" : "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1",
    "assertionCode" : 10057,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}

Mon Jan 21 12:46:33 uncaught exception: assert failed : listDatabases failed:{
    "assertion" : "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:127.0.0.1",
    "assertionCode" : 10057,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
```

Things I tried :

- Going to mongo conf file to desactivate authentication (and restarting mongo and even my server)

PS : Sorry for the formatting, can't figure how to make it right..

Comment: I knw you have shell version 1.6.3 but what MongoDB version do you have? MongoDB 2.3+ is now v8 by default so this could be the problem is you are connecting to a server which is actually running v8 not spidermonkey

Comment: mongod --version returns 1.6.3 if this is what you asked. And mongo --version returns the same

Comment: How did you install MongoDB? When did you install it? 1.6.3 is incredibly old

Comment: I remember installing it not so long ago (a few months) And if I remember well I had an old version so I upgraded it... I don't remember the versions but maybe there is something wrong with it

Comment: Can you try uninstalling that version and installing it from the repos in the manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ using the 10gen list as they show? It sounds like a bad download

Comment: I'll try that and get back here to tell you what happened :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried to uninstall completely mongo and backup everything.
I actually was on the old version of mongo, and learned that there is another package (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

I installed this, re created my users and everything, and it all ended well.